# Add text to a TEXT on a UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

this might seem like a silly question, however I am trying to add text to a text that is already in the UITextView once a button is pressed. For example, let's say I have "Hello World" typed inside the TextView, when the button is pressed the words "This is" would be added to the previous text, creating the sentence "This is Hello World" this is just an example. So far when I press the button the text inside the textview is deleted and replaced. Any thoughts ? Thanks. I've seen some answers here but it hasn't helped me so far...

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: Add the code. Showing what you are doing. I have never used the technology you are using but my guess is that you need to do something like textView.Text = "new text" + textView.Text. From your description it seems you are simply overriding the content of the textView. Then again I have never used the textView and I might be off the mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.text = "This is \(textView.text)"
```

This blindly prepends "This is" every time you tap on button; for instance  the following text is created if you click on the button twice:

```
"This is This is Hello world"
```

You should check the prefix of the string to prevent that from happening:

```
if !textView.text.hasPrefix("This is"):
    textView.text = "This is \(textView.text)"
```

Comment: how would I add the text to every line, for example, first line says "This is Hello World" and the second like has the words "a car" and I want to add "This is" to second line as well, how do I do it ?

Comment: This would probably be better as a new question.

Answer (score -2):

declare global variable `str` when clicked `btn` use following method

```
NSString *str;
- (void)btnClicked{
   str = txtview.text;


}
```

Comment: How would I make it add a text at the beginning of every line from the TextView ?

Comment: NSString *str1=  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What u want %@",str];